# Mockito Error Is Not Applicable for the Arguments (void)

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

Mockito throws error `"The method when(T) in the type Stubber is not applicable for the arguments (void)"` for a class I'm mocking, can't figure out why.

the code in question is:

```
Mockito.when(mockObject.myMethod(Mockito.any(MyExecutionContext.class))).thenReturn(value);
```

I'm aware similar questions have been asked but if somebody could explain a solution for this or point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Solution:

```
Mockito.doReturn(value)
       .when(mockObject)
       .myMethod(Mockito.any(MyExecutionContext‌​.class))
```

Answer (score 7):

Its likely that the return type of the method you are mocking (in above example: mockObject.myMethod) is VOID.

If the return type of the method is 'void' then use this format instead:

```
doThrow(new PersistenceException("Exception occured")).when(mockObject).myMethod(any());

// Note that we can never return a value when return type is void.
```